# DBSCAN clustering using classification algo within each clusters formed

Tags: classification, clustering, dbscan

I am using DBSCAN algo. on "pima indian diabetes" but not able to properly [image: clustering] cluster the data. Also I want to use classification algo within each cluster and compare the accuracy of each cluster and predict the majority one. Kindly help On reducing the eps value  it gives this view[image: eps=0.01]

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    data = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
    clustering = DBSCAN(eps=0.01, min_samples=10).fit(data)
    clusters = len(set(clustering.labels_))
    print("number of clusters : ", clusters)

    def show_clusters(data, clusters):
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=data[:,0], y=data[:,1],            
        label=clusters))
        colors = {-1:'black', 0:'blue', 1:'skyblue', 2:'orange', 
        3:'yellow', 4:'pink', 5:'red'}
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
        grouped = df.groupby('label')

for key, group in grouped:
    group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', label=key, 
    color=colors[key])

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

show_clusters(data, clusters)

[Diabetes dataset link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/akshaydattatraykhare/diabetes-dataset)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of your code are you stuck?

Comment: I am not able to get different clusters it is showing clusters of same color only . i checked with diff dataset also.

Comment: I am not able to get how can I pass the different cluster values to different dataframes so that I can use classification algos on them.

Comment: Please post your code so we can better understand.

Comment: Googling "getting clusters from DBscan" returns a lot (!) of results. One of them being https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py (if you use `sklearn` it also happens to be a part of the documentation)

Comment: @Vishnu Don't post it in the comments. Edit your question and provide your code there

Comment: Most likely you have taken a large eps. Reduce it to .01

Comment: @amolgoel have changed it but not working.

Comment: can you share the sample data, code ?

Comment: @amolgoel done.

Answer (score 0):

Two changes are required:

1. EPS needs to be raised so that you can have larger distance to cover more
   [image]
   As you can see in image above, EPS can not be too low or too high.
2. Plot all cluster in a single grpah for better comparison.
   Added code below

   ```
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)
    clustering = DBSCAN(eps=1, min_samples=10).fit(data)
    print("number of clusters : ", len(set(clustering.labels_)))

    def show_clusters(data, clusters):
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=data[:,0], y=data[:,1],            
        label=clusters))
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

        ax.scatter(df.iloc[:,0],df.iloc[:,1],c = df.label) 

    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()

    show_clusters(data, clustering.labels_)
   ```